# Значение checkbox - как передать в php?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Есть привычный всем checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="hide_field_2">
В активном состоянии он принимает 1, в неактивном - 0.
```

Проблема вся в том, что когда снимаешь checkbox, меняется value на 0, а при отправке Ajax, на сервере его нет. Как сделать так, чтобы на сервер приходило состояние чекбокса(0,1)

Comment: А разве отсутствие этих данных не может трактоваться как "0"?

    $chbx = isset($_POST['hide_field_2']) ? $_POST['hide_field_2'] : 0;

Comment: Никак.

    $value = isset($_POST['hide_field_2']) ? $_POST['hide_field_2'] : false;

Comment: @Etki, два идентичных мнения == true ;)

Comment: Решение не подходит. Потому как имеется массив всех hide_field_*, которые перебираются в цикле. В итоге получится, что ненужные поля будут преобразованы в 0/1.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, а вам разве не это нужно было? Вы же сами написали:

> чтобы на сервер приходило состояние чекбокса(0,1)

Обрабатывая в цикле и проверяя каждое значение, как показано выше, получаете "1" или "0"